# Using Golang package object (.a file)

Tags: go

I am trying to understand the go install command for packages.
I used go install command to install my package and I want to try to use it.
Let's say the original package had the directory "github.com/abc/greeting"
So we can call the method by

```
package main

import "github.com/abc/greeting"

func main() {
    greeting.Greet()
}
```

When I use "go install" for the greeting package, it creates a "greeting.a" in "$GOPATH/pkg/$ARCH/github.com/abc" directory.

How do I use this compiled package object in my code?

Comment: You don’t. It’s used by the build system.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Then I'm just wondering what is the purpose of doing "go install" on a package?

Comment: @Amigo there is none. You can just use `go get`.

Comment: I would say I think a .a file is more useful than a .go in a few cases, e.g., where you're selling software libraries and don't want to give away your source. Of course, you'd need the source or some derived documentation to know what functions are accessible inside the .a .

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> How do I use this compiled package object in my code?

As @JimB answer, no you can't do something like that. However you can use [go plugin API](https://golang.org/pkg/plugin/) to achieve similar result.

In go plugin, the package will be compiled as what-so-called **plugin** file with `.so` extension. Then from the main package you can open the particular plugin and lookup the function. Example:

```golang
p, err := plugin.Open("greeting.so")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
greetFunc, err := p.Lookup("Greet")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

greetFunc.(func())() // call the Greet function
```

---

Also fyi, go had something called **Binary-only package**, however seems like the API will be removed soon https://github.com/golang/go/issues/28152